# Include a widget with webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have an app and I want to include a football table in it. I know how to show websites with webview but not widgets.

The webview should contain a table like this, which is always actual.
https://www.bundesliga-widgets.de/Demo/Bundesligatabelle
How can I show it in the webview?

Comment: You want to display only the table or the complete page?

Comment: only the table. Its not neccesary to display exact this table, but it should be an actual football table of the german bundesliga